# Drawing line and Ellipse using Bresenhem and Mid Point Algorithms

Tags: bresenham

Earlier today I was asked by my lecturer to draw an ellipse like shape that had lines in it using Bresenhem and Mid point, I did not know exactly what was being talked about so I failed, I was then told to go do it home in expectant of another question tomorrow, here is the question
[Image of Question Asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOa6F.png)
I know Stack is not a place where people answer homework but here is the thing, firstly I had search the net, the closet solutions I found was how to deduce the `Decision Parameter` and not how to use the parameter to draw the actual line, I want someone to help me with an example of how I can draw a line, what I need is an example of a line and ellipse drawn using Bresenhen and Mid Point Algorithms and how they did it and not to show me how to answer the entire question, but I would still appreciate if one would answer the question as that will help me truly understand how to deal with such questions.

Here is what I have learnt so far, how to derived a decision parameter still no clue on how to use it to plot a line

```
Y = m(XkXk+1) + b
=m(Xk+1)+b−Yk
=Yk+1−m(Xk+1)−b=Yk+1−m(Xk+1)−b
dlower−dupper=2m(xk+1)−2yk+2b−1
dx(dlower−dupper)=dx(2dydx(xk+1)−2yk+2b−1)
=2dy.xk−2dx.yk+2dy+2dx(2b−1)
=2dy.xk−2dx.yk+C
pk=dx(dlower−dupper)
=2dy.xk−2dx.yk+C
 pk+1=2dy.xk+1−2dx.yk+1+C
 pk+1−pk=2dy(xk+1−xk)−2dx(yk+1−yk)
 pk+1=pk+2dy−2dx(yk+1−yk)
  pk+1=pk+2dy
 Otherwise,
 pk+1=pk+2dy−2dx
```